# Donde guarda Android Studio las imagenes de las descargas

Tags: android-studio

Estoy (migrando a Android Studio) y obteniendo descargas fallidas al tratar de descargar la imagenes de los `dispositivos virtuales` y quisiera poder borrarlos, pues ocupan bastante y tengo que bajar varias imagenes, me imagino que estaran almacendas dentro de algun directorio temporal o algo asi, la pregunta es, en un sistema `GNU/Linux` donde guarda Android studio dichas imagenes.

```
Android Studio 1.5.1
```

**Update:** ya lo encontre con lo que amplio la pregunta, se pueden borrar sin mas o android studio, lleva algun registro por otro lado y se tienen que borrar desde el propio IDE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se guardan en tu carpeta personal y con Ctrl + h muestras los archivos ocultos están en `.android/avd`

**Update:**

- En algunos OS GNU/Linux los `virtual devices` despues de ser creados
  se almacenan en el directorio .android/avd.
- Pero al usa el AVD Manager y descargar las `sistem imagen` estan son
  almacenadas en `Android/Sdk/system-images/` para una `API 23`, donde
  el Sdk esta dentro del directorio Android de su directorio personal
  la ruta seria algo asi
  `/DirectorioPersonal/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-23/`

Comment: su respuesta me hizo indagar un poco pues yo lo habia solucionado de otra manera, y saque la conclusion que amplio en su respuesta Saludos

Comment: y sobre lo de borrarlas (me referio a las sistem imagen que se descarga) las termine borrando del directorio system-images/android-23/ donde dentro se encuentran organizadas en directorios y por ABI. Saludos

Comment: para borrar los virtual devices, los puedes borrar desde el AVD Manger, en la lista de your virtual devices, selecionas el dispositivo que quieres borrar y haces clik con el boton derecho y en la lista desplegable pulsas delete. Saludos